# Group SQL query results by year

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm new in SQL and I need to group the results of a query by year.

In other words, I have this table structure:
`id | title | date`

My current query `SELECT * FROM table`

My current result:

```
array =>
  0 =>
    array =>
      ...
      'date' => string '2018-03-09'
  1 =>
    array =>
      ...
      'date' => string '2018-03-15'
  2 =>
    array =>
      ...
      'date' => string '2017-03-15'
```

And I need something like that:

```
array =>
  0 =>
    array =>
      ...
      'date' => string '2018-03-09'
    array =>
      ...
      'date' => string '2018-03-15'
  1 =>
    array =>
      ...
      'date' => string '2017-03-15'
```

Thanks in advance for help :)

**[EDIT]**

I finally found a way to do what I wanted:

```
$result = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM abstract ORDER BY date DESC");
$array = [];

forEach($result as $res) {
    $year = strtok($res['date'], '-');
    if (!isset($array[$year]))
        $array[$year][0] = $res;
    else
        array_push($array[$year], $res);
}
return $array;
```

Comment: Looks more like a PHP problem how you put the data in your array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want group data by year.

```
    Select id,title,date,DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y') YEAR_GRP from table group by YEAR_GRP
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something you'll want to do in your query, as MySQL can do it much more efficiently, than PHP.

The way to do it is to add a [`GROUP BY` clause](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-group-by/) to your query, which will batch rows in your resultset into a single row, based on a grouping value, which in your case will be [`YEAR(date)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year), as you're looking to group items by the year component in each line's date.

Because you're still looking to have all the results returned, merely grouped by each distinct grouping value, you'll need to use an *Aggregate Function* to combine all the matching lines into an array of values. Luckily MySQL has a function called [`json_objectagg`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-objectagg) which does exactly what you need.

So you'll end up with a query that looks something like:

```
SELECT year(`date`) AS `year`, json_objectagg(id, `date`, title) AS `line`
FROM abstract
GROUP BY `year`
```

Instead of `json_objectagg`, alternatives are e.g. [`json_arrayagg`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg)

```
SELECT year(`date`) AS `year`, json_arrayagg(id, `date`, title) AS `line`
```

...or [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT year(`date`) AS `year`, group_concat(id, `date`, title) AS `line`
```

...depending on what kind of output you require.